# Hide wp-login.php as log-in and redirect it to a custom login page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I'm trying to hide the wp-login.php on my site so I installed the plugin Rename wp-login.php, I renamed it as log-in. Now I want to redirect it to my custom login page so the default login form of wordpress is totally hidden. Is there a way to accomplish this? I have already tried a redirection plugin and the code below however it only supports the wp-login.php and not my new login url:

```
function redirect_login_page(){

// Store for checking if this page equals wp-login.php
$page_viewed = basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

// permalink to the custom login page
$login_page  = get_permalink( '10' );

if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" ) {
    wp_redirect( $login_page );
    exit();
}
}
```

Is there a way to do this without actually altering the wordpress base files?

Answer (score 19):

**Try this**

```
add_action('init','custom_login');
function custom_login(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
  wp_redirect('http://localhost/wordpresstest/blog/');
  exit();
 }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the relative path: wp_redirect('/login') in my case.

Comment: Just adding a comment for helping other persons that are as beginners as I am with Wordpress: I have added the redirect code in my _functions.php_ file from within the _wp-content/themes/<my-theme>_ folder. If someone else has other suggestion, please do share.

Comment: I use this function for redirection to my custom front-end login page. The `exit();` must be removed from the end of it so `wp-login.php` script could process the login action.

Answer (score 19):

Try This Out

```
// Hook the appropriate WordPress action
add_action('init', 'prevent_wp_login');

function prevent_wp_login() {
    // WP tracks the current page - global the variable to access it
    global $pagenow;
    // Check if a $_GET['action'] is set, and if so, load it into $action variable
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
    // Check if we're on the login page, and ensure the action is not 'logout'
    if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php' && ( ! $action || ( $action && ! in_array($action, array('logout', 'lostpassword', 'rp', 'resetpass'))))) {
        // Load the home page url
        $page = get_bloginfo('url');
        // Redirect to the home page
        wp_redirect($page);
        // Stop execution to prevent the page loading for any reason
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yours was the only one that worked for me as it has the conditions.

Comment: Thanks @BigEd. I am glad that my code helped you :)

Comment: As the question says, the questioner wants to **redirect** to a "custom login page". So instead of ```$page = get_bloginfo('url');``` line, we must use ```$page = 'https://your-domain/your-custom-login-page'```. Also the **```exit();```** function must be removed to be able to login actually after redirect.

Comment: @hamid-davodi, your comment was a huge help. This plus the original commenter's code (@Maher Aldous) was successful for me.

Comment: function prevent_wp_login() {
    global $pagenow;
    // Check if a $_GET['action'] is set, and if so, load it into $action variable
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
    // Check if we're on the login page, and ensure the action is not 'logout'
    if( $pagenow == 'wp-login.php' && ( ! $action || ( $action && ! in_array($action, array('logout', 'lostpassword', 'rp', 'resetpass'))))) {
        // Load the log in URL
        $page = '/log-in';
        wp_redirect($page);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'prevent_wp_login');

Answer (score 0):

This works for logging in, but not logging out.
If you're to log out, it redirects you back to the login page, without actually logging you out, as the URL parameter to log out includes /wp-login.php/

I found this to be a better solution:

```
// Redirect from /wp-login.php/ to /login/ with ability to logout & redirect 
add_action('init', 'custom_login');
function custom_login() {
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow === 'wp-login.php' && empty($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    wp_redirect('https://example.com/login/');
    exit();
} elseif ($pagenow === 'wp-login.php?action=logout' && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'logout') {
    wp_redirect('https://example.com/');
    exit();
}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve the results of accessing wordpress admin via custom admin login page using a plugin named [All In One WP Security & Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/).

The All In One WordPress Security plugin will take your website security to a whole new level. This plugin is designed and written by experts and is easy to use and understand.It reduces security risk by checking for vulnerabilities, and by implementing and enforcing the latest recommended WordPress security practices and techniques.

**Your requirement:**

This plugin has ability to hide admin login page. Rename your WordPress login page URL so that bots and hackers cannot access your real WordPress login URL. This feature allows you to change the default login page (wp-login.php) to something you configure.

For more features, refer [plugin codex](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/)